# How to trigger javascript on a date selection on JHTML::_calendar

Tags: joomla-3.x, jquery, calendar

I am using the below code to show a calendar in my form.

```
echo JHTML::calendar("", "timetable_slot_date", "id_timetable_slot_date")
```

What I need is to implement an onChange or onDateSelect javascript (jQuery) to do some Ajax process.

Tried the below code

```
jQuery('#id_timetable_slot_date').change(function() { alert('changed') });
```

This code works only if I manually input the date in the text box.  It doesn't get triggered when I select the date from the popup.

Comment: @Lodder Added the code which I tried...

Comment: After several attempts I noticed that this is not possible and finally I give up. Thanks

Comment: It is possible now, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This is supported directly in core Joomla, at lease in version 3.8.5.

`JHTML::calendar` takes five parameters, the value (date time), element name, element id, date time format and attributes. The attributes element is an associative array and accepts an 'onchange' attribute, which is fired whenever the date or time picker is changed.

For your example, you would use something like:

```
echo JHTML::calendar( 
    "", 
    "timetable_slot_date", 
    "id_timetable_slot_date", 
    "%Y-%m-%d",
    array('onChange'=>'alert(\'hello\');')
);
```

The only bit I had problems with was correctly escaping the quotes around the string being echoed.

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this behavior with a workaround (testing clicks on popup calendar days):

```
jQuery(".icon-calendar").click(function(){
    jQuery("body").on("click",".daysrow",function(){
      /* Check input values and do stuff */
    });
});
```

This will check dinamically if .daysrow (the class including all days of the popup calendar) has been clicked, you just need to check if the value has been actually changed with `jQuery("#inputid").val()`

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from Dom's answer, if you are rendering a calendar using xml `JForm` and `JFormField`, you can write something like this, even though I couldn't find it in Joomla docs:

```
<field name="date" type="calendar" default="NOW" label="COM_EXAMPLE_FORM_LBL_DATE" 
    description="COM_EXAMPLE_FORM_DESC_DATE" hint="COM_EXAMPLE_FORM_LBL_DATE"
    format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" showtime="true" class="example_calendar form-control"
    onchange="calendarValueChange(this)"/>
```

In `onchange`, you can pass the whole Calendar field using `this` so that Javascript can use it, in case it is needed:

```
function calendarValueChange(el) {
  // with jQuery
  if (!jQuery(el).val().length) {
    alert("Calendar value is empty!");
  }
  // without jQuery
  if (!el.value.length) {
    alert("Calendar value is empty!");
  }
}
```